# Spring metro integration cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'wss:binding'

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-integration, java-metro-framework

I try to integrate metro web-service with spring. But I get errors in my `applicationContext.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
        xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core 
                            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
                            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet 
                            https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">
//Some beans

//!!!!!!!!ERROR
    <wss:binding url="/ws">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#newsWebService" />
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>

    <bean id="newsWebService" class="com.news.webservice.NewsWebService">
        <property name="newsBo" ref="newsBo"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Error message:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'wss:binding'.
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd', because 1) could 
     not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

I add lib x-bean-spring-3.7.jar and jaxws-spring-1.8.jar

Also I check spring.schemas in jaxws-spring-1.8.jar and get

```
# See XBEAN-60. To work around the overwriting issue, this file is maintained manually.
# this file is used by Spring to resolve resources locally.
# the key is the system ID and the value is the actual file location in this jar.
http\://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd=spring-jax-ws-core.xsd
http\://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd=spring-jax-ws-servlet.xsd
http\://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/local-transport.xsd=spring-jax-ws-local-transport.xsd
```

I included shemas according with this.

**#UPDATED**
I found something strange. I open in `spring-beans-3.2.0.M1.jar` spring.shemas

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
```

I get applicationContext.xml without error just with `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd` next pair

Please, help me find reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: The previous answer was accepted by eclipse, but triggered an exception at runtime. Here is my final working config**

Use this, the xsd schemas have been moved :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
       xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">
```

Comment: The xmlns do not change (jax-ws.dev.java.net), but the schemas location do (jax-ws.java.net)

Comment: hi there, i have the same issue and the error disappear with this simulation but now I have a runtime error when starting the tomcat.. Do you know how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The java.net hosting web master administrator has caused problems by changing hosting paths.

Change all jax-ws.dev.java.net to jax-ws.java.net and the error disappears as on 28-Aug-2014.

It appears, thousands of developers time got wasted due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line:  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd as it conflicts. Had same issue with similar configuration borrowed off an example on the Internet and this resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

The head of the content of your applicationContext.xml should be:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core" xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because there isn't exist the URL http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/.

The project has been relocated and probably discontinued. Then, I suggest an alternative solution.

1. Download to local the files (spring-jax-ws-core.xsd,spring-jax-ws-servlet.xsd) from the source jar in this URL https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jvnet/jax-ws-commons/spring/jaxws-spring/1.9/jaxws-spring-1.9-sources.jar
2. I have placed in the path "W:/dev/Spring4WebApp/", you can choose another one. I recommend you to upload and publish them in any own server in your company.
3. Modify the appContext with the following lines:

> ```
>  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" 
> xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
> xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
> xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
> xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
> http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
> http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
> http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
> file:///W:/dev/Spring4WebApp/spring-jax-ws-core.xsd
> http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
> file:///W:/dev/Spring4WebApp/spring-jax-ws-servlet.xsd">
> ```

Note the lines starting with "file:///". These lines reference to your local files.
And voilà!! It runs!